# Nginx reload shell command not working with in lua script

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have a dockerised Nginx server created with openresty base image. When a particular endpoint is called it need to update nginx config dynamically. For the changes to reflect I am trying to reload the nginx soon after the changes in config.

with in the container i am able to reload nginx server using `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload`

when i try to use the same with in lua as below ,It doesn't shoot any error but the config changes aren't getting reflected.

```
os.execute("/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command would be run with nginx worker process privileges, and you need to be a root in order to execute this command. You can try to make a particular script for this (lets assume its name would be `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/reload-nginx.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

set the owner of this script no nginx process user (lets assume its name is nginx), and set the [**suid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit on this script

```
chown nginx /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/reload-nginx.sh
chmod +x /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/reload-nginx.sh
chmod u+s /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/reload-nginx.sh
```

and try to execute this script from your lua code:

```
os.execute("/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx-reload.sh")
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but *suid* can only be used with binary executables, not interpreted scripts.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer You are right, I've forgotten that by default the **suid** bit is ignored on shell scripts. My solution would not work unless being wrapped into some compiled code like `int main() { setuid(0); system( "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx-reload.sh" ); return 0; }`

Comment: Thanks alot @IvanShatsky and DarkWiiPlayer for taking time to look into the case. Really appreciate that. Would try to add the shell script and call the execute to run it from my lua

Comment: @Sarga You should not mark an answer as accepted unless you test the solution and ensure that in works in order to not confuse the users with the similar questions. And as DarkWiiPlayer pointed out, most likely this solution would not work.

Comment: @IvanShatsky `system` from a setuid program doesn't work either.

Comment: @IvanShatsky i tried the solution and it worked for me. Had to do a little work around. As mentioned i had to wrap the execution command in a c script. I added the command to compile it and set the user bit permission in docker file and then executed it with in my lua. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can skip calling `nginx` altogether and just send a `HUP` signal to the master process using LuaJITs FFI.

```lua
local process = require 'ngx.process'
local ffi = require 'ffi'
ffi.cdef 'int kill(int pid, int sig);'
ffi.C.kill(process.get_master_pid(), 1)
```

However, this doesn't fix the permissions problem.

One idea that could work is:

- Set up a named pipe with `mkfifo` and make it so your nginx-user can write to it
- Enable the [*Priviliged Agent*](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/process.md#enable_privileged_agent) worker process.
- Set the privileged worker up to listen for input on the named pipe (for example using the `ngx.pipe` module to open `cat` and waiting for input) and send a `HUP` signal to the master process
- Change your `os.execute` code to instead write some line of text into the named pipe to have the privileged agent reload the server.

---

EDIT: If you dislike the `cat` hack, you might want to have a look at https://github.com/slact/ngx_lua_ipc

It might be possible to use IPC to keep the whole thing self-contained within a single nginx server instance, without any file access.